# How to properly include an rd.xml file in a NuGet package?

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-core, .net-native

I'm developing a library that makes heavy use of reflection, and targets both .NET Core (`netstandard1.3`) and full .NET (`net451`).

To make it work with .NET Native (i.e. UWP Release builds), it needs an rd.xml file, which looks like this:

```
<Directives xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2013/01/metadata">
  <Library Name="MyLibrary">
    <!-- bunch of directives here -->
  </Library>
</Directives>
```

I know these directives work because inserting them into the `Application.rd.xml` file of an UWP app using the library works fine, but the app crashes because of missing metadata otherwise.

Using [this blog post](https://metronuggets.com/2015/07/30/my-uwp-nuget-package-is-missing-a-file/), I tried making my library compatible by adding `uap10.0` to the supported frameworks, using the same dependencies as `netstandard1.3` + `System.Runtime`, then adding the following to my `project.json`'s `packOptions`:

```
"files": {
  "include": "Properties/MyLibrary.rd.xml",

  "mappings": {
    "lib/uap10.0/MyLibrary/Properties/MyLibrary.rd.xml": "Properties/MyLibrary.rd.xml"
  }
}
```

The package produced by `dotnet pack -c Release` does indeed contain the `MyLibrary.rd.xml` file in the expected place.

However, .NET Native doesn't pick up the `.rd.xml` file when I use that package (from NuGet, not as a project reference) in an UWP app; the app crashes with missing metadata errors.

What am I missing?

Comment: If you include it as a library resource does it still fail to pick it up? See "No Code Change" here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/05/23/net-native-deep-dive-making-your-library-great/

Comment: @MattWhilden Thanks! I used the equivalent of 'Embedded Resource' in project.json, and it works (see my answer). Looks like that blog post I referenced is out of date.

Comment: Perfect. Glad you're back on track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt Whilden's comment got me on the right path; .xproj-based projects do not have file properties, but the correct equivalent of `Embedded Resource` is `buildOptions/embed` in the framework section, not `packOptions/files`:

```
"uap10.0": {
  "buildOptions": {
    "embed": {
      "include": "Properties/MyLibrary.rd.xml"
    }
  }
}
```