# .Net Native compile error: Type.method will always throw an exception due to the missing method

Tags: .net, native

I'm attempting to compile a UWP app which references Unity (Unity build targeted to WSA/UWP) from a Nuget package in VS 2017.  Everything compiles fine without using "Compile with .NET Native tool chain".  But when I enable .NET Native I get these errors:

> 1>C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.6.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(700,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0003: Method 'NetworkCRC.ReinitializeScriptCRCs(Assembly)' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'TypeExtensions.GetMethod(Type, string, BindingFlags)'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.6.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(700,5): error : Internal compiler error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   1>C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.6.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(700,5): error : Method 'NetworkCRC.ReinitializeScriptCRCs(Assembly)' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'TypeExtensions.GetMethod(Type, string, BindingFlags)'. There may have been a missing assembly.

NetworkCRC.ReinitializeScriptCRCs() comes from UnityEngine.Networking.dll.  I'm not using NetworkCRC.ReinitializeScriptCRCs() in my code.

From the answer here:
[UWP - .NET Native tool chain compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748389/uwp-net-native-tool-chain-compilation-error)

> the compiler is walking your entire application at compile time in order to generate native code for everything that it thinks you're going to call.

That explains how this is happening.  And I've found other similar problems:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/20d3040a-c85c-4549-85a5-972d8686cc7a/uwpcant-compile-uwp-app-with-net-native-in-release-mode?forum=wpdevelop

I've also found the help for rd.xml files:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/runtime-directives-rd-xml-configuration-file-reference

Questions:

- Can I tell .NET native to just ignore a specific type or method in
  the rd.xml file? If not can I give .NET Native hints on how to handle the method?
- Is this a problem with NetworkCRC.ReinitializeScriptCRCs or TypeExtensions.GetMethod?
- Will Fixes in the rd.xml in my VS Project work on assemblies in the nuget package or will I need to apply those fixes to a xml file inside the package as per this thread [How to properly include an rd.xml file in a NuGet package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39687011/how-to-properly-include-an-rd-xml-file-in-a-nuget-package)

I know Unity does a lot of weird stuff combing assemblies at compile time, is it possible Unity is missing a reference to another assembly due to reflection etc?

PS:  I know that removing:

```
<Assembly Name="*Application*" Dynamic="Required All" />
```

from Default.rd.xml will fix the compile issue.  I'd like to know how to apply a more targeted approach.

Comment: From the Unity docs: "This is very rarely required".  So very high odds that this warning is not going to hurt you, raised to the umpteenth power by your code not using it.  Testing the .NET Native image is always necessary to ensure it did not break your program, the only reason you have it on your machine.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks Hans, and that's exactly why I want to try and remove just this method from .NET Native build.